# No GNU screen sockets found after SSH logout [Steam Deck]

Tags: arch-linux, gnu-screen, steam

I am unable to use screen or tmux to keep a process running after a logout. Usually on my Linux servers I can use GNU screen to keep my process running after a logout but on Valve's Steam Deck which runs a derivative of Arch this does not work.
I have already disabled the immutable root filesystem using `sudo steamos-readonly disable` and installed GNU screen using pacman as it was not installed by default. I can create new screen sessions with `screen -S test` and detach from them. `screen -ls` does show the screen and I am able to reattach it. After I logout and log back in does `screen -ls` return `No Sockets found in /run/screens/S-deck`. This also happens if I use tmux. Additionally if I have 2 SSH connections the moment I logout of the SSH session that created the screen do I lose the screen any the process running inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `KillUserProcesses=yes` is set in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and if so (or if it isn't set at all), change it to `no`

Comment: Does not work. Originally all of the options in logind.conf were commented out with #.